# insert values into mysql table in python

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector, pymongo-3.x

To insert values into mysql table in python. Below is the code  extracting mongodb collection data and inserting it into mysql table in python.

```python
     def insert():   
                           
        client=MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')  
                     
        db=client['mydb']                          #database                                               
        coll=db['data']                            #collection                                 
        mongo_docs = coll.find({},{'_id':0})       #mongo cursor removed '_id' in projection                            
        fieldnames = list(mongo_docs[0].keys())    #all the column names in the dataset
                     
        for record in mongo_docs:                                   
                values = list(record.values())     #all the values in the dataset                         
                #print(values) 
                                
        connection=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",database="mydb",password="passwd")
        cursor1=connection.cursor()                      
        connection.commit()                        #mysql connection
       
        count=0                         
        for i in fieldnames:                         
              count=count+1
                                
        qmark=[]                
        a=0                    
        while a<count:  
                qmark.append('%s')
                a=a+1
        
        q=','.join(tuple(qmark))
        
        query="INSERT INTO  ndata VALUES ('%s')"%(q)
        
        cursor1.executemany("INSERT INTO  ndata VALUES (%s)" %(q),(values))
```

This code throws an error:
`ProgrammingError: Could not process parameters: int(82506), it must be of type list, tuple or dict`

The values in the dataset are like this:
`[82506, '1945-12-31', 0, '', 29.44444444, 17.22222222, 23.33333333, 0, '', 45, 12, 31, 0, '', '', 85, 63, 74, 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`
which has empty strings inside it.

q in the code produces %s, generates %s which equal to number of columns in the dataset. Here 31 columns in the dataset so there are 31 of (%s,%s,%s.....) in q

The same code with when executed with

```python
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO  ndata VALUES (%s)" %(q),(values))
```

in place of `cursor.executemany()` runs without any errors but it does not insert any values into the table in mysql.

What changes should i make to insert multiple rows of values at once ?
or how could i insert it row by row?

Comment: Please format the code at the bottom for better understanding

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: if it works for `execute()` then you have wrong data in `values`. It seems you have only one row of data (and it works with `execute()` which expect only one row of data) but `executemany()` expect list with many results. As for me you create `values` in wrong way. You should create `values = []` before `for`-loop and you should use `values.append(...)` instead of `values = ...`

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it but I think you create `values` in wrong way.

If it works for `execute()` then `values` has only one row of data  but `executemany()` expects list with many rows of data.

And this may suggest that you create `values` in wrong way.

You should create list `values = []` before `for`-loop and you should use `values.append(...)` instead of `values = ...` to add new row to list (instead of keeping only one row in variable).

```py
# --- before loop ---

values = []

# --- loop ---

for record in mongo_docs:                                   
    row = list(record.values())
    values.append(row)

# --- after loop ---

print(values)
```

---

**BTW:**

Shorter

```
count = len(fieldnames)
```

and

```
qmark = ['%s'] * count
q = ','.join(qmark)
```

---

```py
def insert():   
                           
    client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')  # PEP8: spaces around `=`
                 
    db = mongo_client['mydb']
    collection = db['data']
    mongo_docs = collection.find({},{'_id':0})
    fieldnames = list(mongo_docs[0].keys())
                 
    values = []
    
    for record in mongo_docs:
        row = list(record.values())
        values.append(row)
                            
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", database="mydb", password="passwd")  # PEP8: spaces after `,`
    cursor = connection.cursor()
   
    count = len(fieldnames)
                            
    qmark = ['%s'] * count
    q = ','.join(qmark)     # no need `tuple()`
    
    query = f"INSERT INTO ndata VALUES ({q})"   # modern `f-string` instead of very old `%`
    
    cursor.executemany(query, values)
        
    connection.commit()  # after `executemany('INSERT ...')`
```

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)